# FFmpeg memory usage increases indefinitely when trying to lower the FPS of a video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, io

I have a certain process (loop) where I combine frames into a video with `opencv` and then change its FPS from 45 to 5 with `FFmpeg`, save it as a new video, delete the old one, split the new video into frames and finally delete the frame-reduced video.

It seems that with every iteration of `FFmpeg`, which is this line:

```
os.system(f'ffmpeg -i {original_vid_path} -r 5 -y {new_vid_path}')
```

My RAM usage goes up by ~400MB or so with each video until it reaches the maximum of 16GB.

The videos themselves are around 30 seconds to 3 minutes long.

Is this behavior intended? is there any way to free up memory after each frame reduction? I prefer not to stop & resume each time since I have around 1400 videos.

Comment: What's the resolution? Also, your process description sounds very redundant; can you just pick every 9 frame and call it a day? `-r 5` from 45 fps video does exactly that.

Comment: Run a quick test in Windows Python with `smptebars=r=45:s=1920x1080:d=180` source (using `subprocess.run`), looping the encoding 10 times, FFmpeg process maintained 900 MB every time it was spawned. Are you certain the memory leak is in FFmpeg and not elsewhere?

Comment: @kesh That was my initial "trivial" solution but I remember that when I researched about it some members here said it's better not to do that (can't find those comments now), furthermore I ran a `memory profiler` and found that the leakage on `cv2.imread(filename)`

Comment: I'm curious to know the reasoning against the "trivial" solution because `-r 5` is an inferior solution as you are re-encoding your image twice (i.e., quality loss at each stop) while you can get away with none with the original image quality. Is the motion on the video fairly fast? If that's the case and you want to blur the image to avoid temporal aliasing to do so you need to use `framerate` filter instead of `fps` filter that `-r` option implicitly uses. Just my 2 cents.